# Elm extensible records init

Tags: elm

I'm trying to create a decorator type to hold state around some item. This item could be an email, news bulletin, reminder, etc etc... I thought this would do it but I'm getting an error.

```
type alias Model a =
  {a | pinned : Bool, done : Bool, trunc : Bool}

init : a -> Model(a)
init cont = {cont | pinned <- False, done <- False, trunc <- False}
```

Here is the compiler error:

```
Detected errors in 1 module.
## ERRORS in .\.\Item.elm ######################################################

-- TYPE MISMATCH -------------------------------------------------- .\.\Item.elm

The type annotation for `init` does not match its definition.

20| init : a -> Model(a)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Could not unify user provided type variable `a`. The most likely cases are:

  1. The type you wrote down is too general. It says any type can go through
     but in fact only a certain type can.
  2. A type variable is probably being shared between two type annotations.
     They are treated as different things in the current implementation, so
     Try commenting out some type annotations and see what happens.

As I infer the type of values flowing through your program, I see a conflict
between these two types:

    a

    { d | done : a, pinned : b, trunc : c }
```

The types i'm going to want to decorate are for instance:

```
type alias Email =
  { from: String
  , to: String
  , title: String
  , body: String
  , date: String
  }

type alias Reminder =
  { body: String
  , created: String
  }
```

After changing the '<-' to '=' i get the following vague syntax error:

```
Detected errors in 1 module.
## ERRORS in .\.\Item.elm ######################################################

-- SYNTAX PROBLEM ------------------------------------------------- .\.\Item.elm

I ran into something unexpected when parsing your code!

21| init cont = { cont | pinned = False, done = False, trunc = False }
                                       ^
I am looking for one of the following things:

    a closing bracket '}'
    a field access like .name
    an expression
    an infix operator like (+)
    more letters in this name
    whitespace
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see from the syntax you're using that this is not [Elm **0.16**](http://elm-lang.org/blog/compilers-as-assistants), which is the version where the record update syntax changed. In your current version of Elm you can do:

```
type alias Model a =
  {a | pinned : Bool, done : Bool, trunc : Bool}

init : a -> Model a -- the parentheses were superfluous so I removed them
init cont0 =
  let cont1 = { cont0 | pinned = False }
      cont2 = { cont1 | done = False }
      cont3 = { cont2 | trunc = False }
  in cont3
```

Since according to the type annotation, you're *adding* fields, not *updating* fields. You can only add one field at a time, sadly, so please excuse the awkward syntax.

Note that in Elm **0.16** [field addition syntax has been removed](http://elm-lang.org/blog/compilers-as-assistants#simplified-records). It wasn't used very much and newcomers found the `=` versus `<-` very confusing. So the field addition was removed and the update syntax was changed to use `=`. This means that in a new version of Elm you won't be able to write your init function this way anymore. See the blog post and mailing list for strategies to rewrite programs with extensible records to use other types to model things.

---

To give one example of how you may change your program to still work with Elm 0.16+:

```
type alias Model a =
  { submodel: a, pinned: Bool, done: Bool, trunc: Bool }

init : a -> Model a
init submodel = Module submodel False False False
-- This makes use of the generated record constructor
--  that came with the type alias definition.
-- You could also write: 
--  { submodel: submodel, pinned: False, done: False, trunc: False }
```

Comment: I get a syntax error. I'm using 15.1. I've edited my question. In any case I'll check out the mailing list.

Comment: oh darn, I think you can only add one field at a time in 15.1 :( I'll edit my answer, sorry @MichielAriens

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for this info @Apanatshka ! Do you any recommendations on how to write this in Elm 0.17? I'm having a difficult time figuring this out.

Comment: @Apanatshka Thanks!!